# R package `libs` directory too large after compilation to submit on CRAN

Tags: r, package

I am the developer of the following package https://gitlab.inria.fr/gdurif/pCMF and I have a problem: the compiled library is too big.

When I check it with `R CMD check`, I get the following note regarding the size of the compiled library:

> checking installed package size ... NOTE   installed size is 31.0Mb   sub-directories of 1Mb or more:
>       libs  30.8Mb

My package is based on `C++` code interfaced thanks to the package [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) and heavily uses the algebra template library `Eigen` based on the package `RcppEigen`.

Since Eigen is templated, I think that the compiled library can become large. However, I would like to submit my package on the `CRAN` and I have no idea at all how I could solve this.

Thanks

Comment: You don't "solve" this.  It is a NOTE, ie less than a WARNING or ERROR.  Hundreds of C++ based packages have the same, including Rcpp itself.  It will not stop CRAN.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wasn't sure if it was a big deal or not.